# Comparing only dates From the database Timestamp Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an attendance system, now I want to compare the date of the day to the date in the database, I have my date in the database in Timestamp format, now what I only need is the date and the year, I want to compare it to the current date, Here is my code:

```
        $userinput=Input::get('empid');

        $mydate=Carbon::now()->addHours(8);
        $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

        if ($newdate==$datefromdatabaseifexist) 
        {


        }

        else

        DB::table('attendances')->insert(
        array('user_id' => $userinput, 'logon' =>$newdate)
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to check if the date is the same (not necessarily the same year)

```
$dateInDB = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($timestamp);
$dateToCompare = Carbon::now()->addHours(8);

if($dateToCompare->isBirthday($dateInDB)){
    //do something because this day matches
}
```

Funny name I know. If you need to also check year then use `Carbon::isSameDay()`

For your reference: [Carbon Documentation](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon#api-comparison)

Comment: where is the if here? I'm just new to laravel and OOP sorry

Comment: I clarified my answer. isBirthday and isSameDay return Boolean values (true or false) so they can be used directly in if statements.